# How to add database views as part of IDatabaseInitializer

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I would like to map a POCO class to a database view. My goal is to create the view using a custom database Initializer (Implementing `IDatabaseInitializer<T>)`

Unless I'm mistaken, I must decorate the class that maps to the view with the [Table("MyViewName"] attribute.  However when I do this `Database.CreateIfNotExists()` will create a table called `MyViewName`, before I get a chance to execute the `SqlQuery` command that creates the view.

I suspect I'm doing something out of order, but with only one method in the IDatabaseInitializer interface to work with, I can't see what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to simply let the CreateIfNotExists do it's thing, and then drop the newly created table and replace it with a view.  Seems somewhat hackish but it does work.

```
if (context.Database.CreateIfNotExists())
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"drop table MyCustomView");
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"create view MyCustom View as ...");
}
```